# RESTEasy - How to Set Basic Authentication to ClientRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpclient, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy (implementation of JAX-RS).
I can't find a way to set basic, preemptive, authentication to ClientRequest.

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("<url>");
// -- here I want to add basic-preemptive authentication --
ClientResponse response = request.get();
System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class));
```

What the correct way to do it?
Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782602/rest-http-authentication-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the constructors in `ClientRequest`, you will see that one of them takes a string and a `ClientExecutor`.

So you can do something like this:

```
ApacheHttpClient4Executor executor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor();
DefaultHttpClient client  = (DefaultHttpClient) executor.getHttpClient();
client.addRequestInterceptor(new MyPreemptiveAuthInterceptor(), 0);

ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://my-url", executor);
```