# Authenticate resteasy service using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, resteasy, restful-authentication

I have developed a restful web services using RestEasy.

Now I want to add some authentication features to the client when they invoke the service. e.g: they should login first.

First I just want very basic auth, I hardcode a username and password in spring context xml file.

Are there anyway to implement that? thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782602/rest-http-authentication-how