# How to secure Cxf jax-ws webservice?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I am new in web services. I have created web services using spring with CXF jax-ws implementation.
Suppose I have "`HelloWebService`" in that I have webmethod "`sayHello()`" which will return string.

when I hit url:

```
localhost:8080/ProjName/service/HelloWebService?wsdl
```

It shows me wsdl on browser.

Now, I want to ask `username and password` when user hit this url on browser.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I partially understand you but I think you would like to make a rest authentication. I had to do similar some months ago, and I came across this answer. [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782602/rest-http-authentication-how)

Answer (score 0):

You can use InterceptorProviders for passing the credentials or the parameters you want to pass

[REFER](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)

Answer (score 0):

to make your URL password protected in Spring

you can use authentication-manager tag in spring.xml (your spring config file)