# REST Authentication: CDI safe? Which scope for CDI @Produces?

Tags: java, rest, cdi, resteasy, jboss7.x

I'm using ReastEasy in a JBoss-7 environment and currently implementing security features. I'm using HTTP Basic with an SSL connection. Adding and evaluating the header parameter is easy (Thanks to [Passing parameters in the message header with a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892682)):

```
@Provider @ServerInterceptor
public class RestSecurityInterceptor implements PreProcessInterceptor
{
  @EJB MyBean fUser;
  private MyUser user;  

  @Override
  public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method)
                                                     throws UnauthorizedException
  {
     // do some some stuff. If the request is authenticated I get a MyUser      
    user = ...
  }

  @Named @Produces @SessionScoped
  public MyUser getCurrentUser() {return user;}
}
```

This works fine, also the `@Produces` and `@Inject` in my REST service work like a charm.

```
@Path("/rest")
public class MyService extends Application
{
  @Inject private MyUser currentUser;

  @GET @Path("/test")
  public String test()
  {
    return "Hello "+currentUser.getName();
  }
}
```

Now my question: Is it *safe* to implement the security for REST this way (I don't want a discussion about HTTP Basic pro/cons, let's focus on CDI)? Especially I'm wondering if I can use CDI like described and if I have chosen the right scope with `@SessionScoped`?

Answer (score 0):

Session scope won't work. There have already been a few questions about REST and the session scope. The session scope is not active for JAX-RS nor JAX-WS calls.

Comment: In my application, I inject an `@SessionScoped` POJO `A` into a REST endpoint which has default scope. After the first call to this endpoint, all subsequent calls of the same client get the instance of `A` that is bound to its session. My interpretation of this situation is that session scope works for JAX-RS and is active; or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Interesting, it shouldn't be active, because there's nothing by default to tie requests to a particular session. Section 6.7.2 of the CDI spec doesn't mention it being active for web services.